# Just started sqlite. How do I do refined searches?

Tags: database, sqlite

For example I got a table of actors. I need to find all actors born after the year 1956 (which uses birth_year in table). How do I use the select command to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your table is named `actors`, you'd do

```
SELECT * FROM actors WHERE birth_year > 1956;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM actors WHERE birth_year > 1956;
```